# Music player that allows me to rate my music files

Tags: software-rec, music, music-player

I seek a music player which will let me rate my music and later play highly rated ones. I am aware that rhythmbox can do this, but seek alternatives with better UI.

Other features sought:

- Ability to add particular folder to a playlist with ease.
- saving playlists to file
- browsing audio collection by artist, album etc..

Answer (score 0):

"better UI" is a subjective matter that you'll ultimately have to decide for yourself, but I would suggest **[Amarok](https://amarok.kde.org/)** which I believe does all of the things you are looking for.

In fact Amarok has its own automatic [track scoring system](https://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Various/FAQ#How_are_track_scores_determined.3F), which can also be [manually changed](https://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Various/FAQ#How_do_I_manually_change_a_track.27s_score.3F), whilst still offering the more traditional [stars based rating system](https://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Various/FAQ#But_I_also_want_that_stars_system_like_in_other_players.21).

So [install](https://community.kde.org/Amarok/GettingStarted/Download) it and give it a go... you'll find all the details in the [Amarok Manual](https://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual) and if you need a hand there's always the [Amarok Forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=127).

Hope that helps! :-)